# Minecraft The Nether 21106 microworld set bags?

Tags: piece-information

Can anyone tell me how many plastic pouches come in this set? My box has five plastic bags and two instruction books. And also one long orange piece separately. I'm trying to find out if I am missing any pouches before I open them.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 6):

Based on the [brickset review](https://brickset.com/reviews/46685) the set contains 5 bags an 2 instructions  and 1 loose brick separator (see photo of the box), so I think you have the complete set

[image]
[image]
[image]